# Dropdown options can't access with jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a drop down in my webpage.It's a aspx page.But i am try to access the drop down from JavaScript.here is my code.
This code is working.

```
var a = document.getElementById('myDropdown');
alert(a.options.length);
```

This code is not working

```
var a = $('#myDropdown');
alert(a.options.length);
```

i am getting the following error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Any one have any idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$('#myDropdown') is a jQuery object and you are treating a like a dom object.  Try changing

```
var a = $('#myDropdown');
```

to

```
var a = $('#myDropdown')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the clientID, ASPX controls are rendered differently on the page. You can also target the controls class using normal selectors.

```
var a = $('#<%=myDropdown.ClientID%>'); <-- ID
var b = $(".className") <--- Class selector.
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery and js doesnt select the same thing.

There is 2 way to get the number of action with JQ :

```
$('#dropdown')[0].options.lenght; //That select the container like getElement
```

or

```
$('#dropdown').children().length // That's pure jq counting the children (options)
```